# How to copy data from a form+sub-form to table in ms access?

Tags: forms, ms-access, insert-update

I have created a form that has a subform attached. I have a button that runs a query to delete the record but first I want to copy the data from including all subform information if available to a table. I have used the following code but nothing happens. please! what am I have missing?

```
Private Sub Command63_Click() 
Dim db As Database, delfile As Recordset, Criteria As String 
Set db = CurrentDb 
Set delfile = db.OpenRecordset("DelFile", DB_OPEN_DYNASET) 

'add data to deleted taxpayer file table 
With delfile 
    .AddNew 
    !DeletedBy = (Forms!MainMenu!username) 
    !Branch = Me.Branch 
    !TaxType = Me.TaxType 
    !Volume = Me.Volume 
    !Keyedby = Me.Keyedby 
    !DateKeyed = Me.DateKeyed 
    !CreatedAt = Me.CreatedAt 
    !Comment = Me.Comment 
End With 
delfile.Close 
db.Close 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set all of your field values you need to include a `.update` for the changes to take affect.  Your new code would look like this.

```
Private Sub Command63_Click() 
Dim db As Database, delfile As Recordset, Criteria As String 
Set db = CurrentDb 
Set delfile = db.OpenRecordset("DelFile", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)

'add data to deleted taxpayer file table 
With delfile 
    .AddNew 
    !DeletedBy = (Forms!MainMenu!username) 
    !Branch = Me.Branch 
    !TaxType = Me.TaxType 
    !Volume = Me.Volume 
    !Keyedby = Me.Keyedby 
    !DateKeyed = Me.DateKeyed 
    !CreatedAt = Me.CreatedAt 
    !Comment = Me.Comment
    .Update
End With 
delfile.Close 
db.Close 
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the .Update in the code but I'm now getting an error. after putting it in. btw the form Im pulling the data from is bound to a different table, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: i just saw the error i had. along with the missing .update line i was leaving out a required field from the table to which i was sending the information.